# What is the purpose of ///<comment> </comment> in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, frameworks, visual-studio-2012

I searched the net and found no results explaining the usage of this comment block. Therefore, I hope someone can explain to me the reason behind this style of comment.

```
///<comment> Text goes here. </comment>
```

Comment: it looks like a comment. ;-) well more seriously it looks like part of in-source-code documentation comment, sort of like javadoc. possibly if you look up visual studio's variant of it you will find the line explained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are XML documentation comments.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx

Comment: Also as a note, whatever you type there shows up in Itellisense (the popups that show up when you type in a class or function name)

Answer (score 1):

It's XML syntax often use by Software aggregator and Visual Studio Itself to generate help/doc file.
Such as Sandcastle

Comment: Careful with the term meta-data, in C# that seems to have special meaning.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx says "The XML doc comments are not metadata; they are not included in the compiled assembly and therefore they are not accessible through reflection."

Answer (score 0):

They are also recognized by doxygen as documentation comments:
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html

**Edit 1: Correction**
The beginning "///" is recognized by doxygen, not the `</comment>`.